# Value of HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute

Tags: html, iframe, attributes, sandbox

I've been reading up on HTML5's `sandbox` attribute for `<iframe>`s. According to the documentation the `sandbox` attribute allows a developer to selectively restrict what actions can be done in an `<iframe>`. Is the sandbox attribute purely a security measure? Does the `sandbox` attribute enable web designers to implement any new functionality and if so can anyone point to any examples?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it is purely a security feature, but it *does* allow new functionality as well. Take for example embedding third party (user) content (e.g. HTML files). Traditionally you would need to set up a separate domain from which you would serve that content, now however you can simply serve it from wherever you want to and have it treated as if it's from a separate domain.

On top of that it can prevent this third party content from doing certain things, which you could not have prevented previously like:

- `allow-top-navigation`: Preventing it from breaking out
- `allow-pointer-lock`: Preventing it from taking the cursor hostage
- `allow-popups`: Preventing it from breaking out through popups
- `allow-scripts`: Simply blocking all scripts (could also have been done through CSP)

Realistically the combination of the `sandbox` attribute combined with controlled CSP headers gives an incredible amount of control to run third party code in a safe environment. It's not 100% there yet, but we're getting quite close.

Comment: So does it allow https to be used in situations where it previously could not have been used?

Comment: @BenPearce I have no idea what you mean with that question... HTTPS can and could be used anywhere where HTTP could be used and it has nothing whatsoever to do with all this as far as I can think of right now (though I might be forgetting about something...).

Comment: I'm talking about the 'Lock' icon by the URL, that signifies that the site meets a security requirement. Can a regular iframe break that and if so can a Sandboxed iframe preserve it?

Comment: @BenPearce Ah, mixed content warnings and the like? As far as I know no browser uses `sandbox`ing to affect those warnings. The reason for this would probably be that determining which URL to load still happens in the secure environment, so MiTM'ing the insecure sandbox would still allow a lot of security exploits and give a false sense of security to the user.

Comment: **"Allow"** means **"Prevent"**? So to **allow ALL** means we must **remove the sandbox attribute** entirely? Even so I can't make my frame content button that invokes jQuery code work either. My jQuery code is inside the frame content, not calling any function from the parent / container page. It doesn't allow my jQuery to be executed either. FYI, the parent page is **JSFiddle**.

Answer (score 3):

The sandbox can actually be pretty handy in testing. Consider the following:

**tester.html**

```
<script> document.cookie='foo=bar' </script>
<iframe src=testee.html>
```

**testee.html**

```
<script> console.log(document.cookie) </script>
```

When loading tester.html you will see on the console `"foo=bar"` which was dumped by testee.html.

Now add to the `iframe` the `sandbox` attribute and the cookie is gone - the sandbox created a separate runtime environment for testee.html, where it doesn't get cookie pollution from other pages that were/are open in the browser during the development process. So when you need a sterile test bed but can't or don't want to clear the browser cache, here's a quick and simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox attribute does not enable any extra functionality, it only restricts the functionality of the iframe. The only reason to use it is as a security measure.

Answer (score 2):

The iframe `sandbox` is purely a security feature. A good resource is always the W3 [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox).

> When the attribute is set, the content is treated as being from a unique origin, forms, scripts, and various potentially annoying APIs are disabled, links are prevented from targeting other browsing contexts, and plugins are secured.

Comment: So does the sandbox attribute allow you to do stuff with iframes over 'https' that you could previously only do with 'http'?

Comment: The `sandbox` attribute adds restrictions. The keywords re-enables functionality the `iframe` would already have without the `sandbox` attribute.

Comment: What I'm asking is, are there circumstances where an non-sandbox iframe will break https but a sandboxed iframe will not.

Comment: I think you should update your question and title to specify that.